# Как добавить дополнительные поля в форму регистрации плагина theme my login wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, регистрация

На сайте с движком `wordpress` и установленным плагином [Theme My Logi](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)n хочу в шаблон регистрации к существующим полям (Логин, пароль, e-mail) добавить следующие поля (Фамилия, Имя, Мобильный телефон, пол), но проблема в том, что эти поля в бд не сохраняет.. Как их правильно добавить?

```
<p><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_login' ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></p>
      <p><label for="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">Фамилия:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="regular-text" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>"  /></p>
      <p><label for="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">Имя:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="regular-text" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'first_name' ); ?>" /></p>
<?php
      $show_password_fields = apply_filters( 'show_password_fields', true, $profileuser );
      if ( $show_password_fields ) :
      ?>
      <div id="password">
        <p><label for="pass1">Пароль:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1" size="16" autocomplete="off" /></p>
        <p><label for="pass2">Повторить пароль:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" size="16" autocomplete="off" /></p>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <p><label for="user_email">E-mail:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" class="regular-text" /></p>
      <p><label for="user_tel">Мобильный телефон:<span class="necessarily">*</span></label><input type="tel" name="tel_number" pattern=".{7,}" id="tel_number<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'tel_number' ); ?>" class="regular-text"  size="20" /></p>
      <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="user_gender">Пол:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="мужской" <?php checked('мужской', get_user_meta($profileuser->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>мужской
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="женский" <?php checked('женский', get_user_meta($profileuser->ID, 'gender', true)); ?>>женский
      </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так - ответ [здесь](https://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/adding-extra-registration-fields/):
добавляем новые поля в тему

```
<p>
    <label for="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'First name', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'first_name' ); ?>" size="20" tabindex="20" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>" size="20" tabindex="20" />
</p>
```

проводим валидацию:

```
function tml_registration_errors( $errors ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'empty_first_name', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your first name.' );
    if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'empty_last_name', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your last name.' );
    return $errors;
}
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'tml_registration_errors' );
```

сохраняем поля:

```
function tml_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( !empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name'] );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name'] );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'tml_user_register' );
```